# Unable to start Packetbeat in elastic 7.5.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, packetbeat, elastic-beats

I am using elastic stack of version 7.5.1 with x-pack installed and i'm getting the following error when i trying to run packetbeat.

Please help me solve it.

```
2020-01-08T11:56:23.202+0530    ERROR   instance/beat.go:916    Exiting: Sniffer main loop failed: Error starting sniffer: any: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
Exiting: Sniffer main loop failed: Error starting sniffer: any: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Seems like the user running packetbeat lacks in proper permissions? What user is running the beat?

Comment: are you refering to the elastic x-pack users or my linux login users ?

Comment: The linux user. If you have a daemon, the daemon user then. Check if this error persists when you start the beat as root - only for the verification, not as a long term solution

Answer (score 0):

Start Pakcketbeat with Root access. It will solve this permission problem.

It is obvious from error:

```
 Error starting sniffer: any: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted
```

That the current user does not have permission to capture socket activities.